# simple_html_dom class, What actually plaintext function returns?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I think i don't get it. I tried to parse some html page :

```
<select name="sel">
  <option value="val0">-please select me-</option>
  <option value="val1">some selection</option>
</select>
```

Im using the Simple_html_dom class :

```
foreach($html->find('select') as $s) {
    if ($html->find('option',1) != false) {
      $tempoption = $html->find('option',1)->plaintext;
      echo $tempoption; //shows 'some selection'
    }
}
```

but, then if i simply use this line :

```
$value='';
if ( $tempoption == 'some selection')
   $value='79';
echo $value; //doesn't shows anything (empty variable?)

//or this one :
if ( strcmp($tempoption, 'some selection'))
   $value='79';
echo $value; //Nope.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out the code just as you had it there and `$value` DID end up with 79. But I think that you must have more to your HTML than that tiny snippet. The thing in your code that stood out most to me was the fact that you are wrapping the conditionals in a loop that goes through all the selects of the HTML, but you are not making use of the individual select elements that you get from the loop, so the foreach loop seems pointless..

Have a look at this:

```
foreach($html->find('select option') as $o) 
{
  $o_label = $o->plaintext;
  if($o_label=='some selection') echo 'PERFECT MATCH: '.$o_label."\n"; 
  else if(stripos($o_label, 'some selection')!==false) echo 'LOOSE MATCH: '.$o_label."\n"; 
  else echo 'DOES NOT MATCH: '.$o_label."\n";
}
```

When given HTML:

```
<select name="sel">
  <option value="val0">-please select me-</option>
  <option value="val1">1 some selection</option>
  <option value="val1">This does not match</option>
  <option value="val1">some selection</option>
  <option value="val1">Another non-matching label</option>
  <option value="val1">some selection 3</option>
  <option value="val1">One more that does not match</option>
  <option value="val1">4 SoME sElEcTIon 4</option>
</select>
```

The output will be:

```
DOES NOT MATCH: -please select me-
LOOSE MATCH: 1 some selection
DOES NOT MATCH: This does not match
PERFECT MATCH: some selection
DOES NOT MATCH: Another non-matching label
LOOSE MATCH: some selection 3
DOES NOT MATCH: One more that does not match
LOOSE MATCH: 4 SoME sElEcTIon 4
```